# 'TrueOS Desktop' installer loops endlessly, never succeeds in completing the installation

Tags: freebsd, bsd, trueos

I am trying [TrueOS](https://www.trueos.org), the evolution of [PC-BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC-BSD). I [downloaded](https://www.trueos.org/downloads/) the 'TrueOS-Desktop-2016-09-09-x64.iso'.

When running the installer in [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com) 12.0.1 virtual machine the main menu for the installer appears, with a few options to choose from. I let that menu expire after about several seconds to auto-boot. I see all the installer scripts reporting to the console.

But then the main menu for installer re-appears, deja-vu. Lather, rinse, repeat. The **main menu and installer scripts keep running in a loop**, endlessly. I never get any further than seeing the installer scripts console output fly-by, never see any success in booting the TrueOS environment.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would someone create a new tag for `TrueOS`?

Comment: You might try posting this question on their forum/mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

## Fixed in 2016-09-20 release

Seems to be fixed in new TrueOS installer for 2016-09-20. Or perhaps fixed in the new Parallels 12.0.2 update.

I [downloaded](http://download.trueos.org/master/amd64/) the file `TrueOS-Desktop-2016-09-20-x64-DVD.iso`. Pointed the Parallels Wizard to that .iso file. When prompted by Parallels, I identified the type of OS by choosing `Other` > `FreeBSD`. After much console output, the graphical installer for TrueOS does indeed appear.

---

Tip, after clicking `Finish` in the graphical installer, you are returned to the character-oriented window (COW) installer. There, choose the last option to reboot the system.

---

Running Parallels 12.0.2 on a host MacBook Pro running Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 with 16 gigs physical memory.